# Extension Manager stuck on "Please Wait"

Tags: admin, error, extensions, magento-2.2.5

Whenever I try to access the extension manager in the admin section it goes to the "Please Wait" message and then stays there indefinitely.

[image]

There don't seem to be any errors in the developer console so I'm not sure what is happening here.

Comment: Have you enter valid Public & Private Keys?

Comment: Yes. I've been using the extensions manager quite frequently until now. It's always been OK before this.

Comment: Hi @CJNotts, any errors if you right click > inspect on the console in the browser window?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. No. None that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloaded a backup edition of my site and this now seems to be working. Seems to be down to an extension that I installed via composer which was not agreeing with the magento system.

After some additional research this issue could be caused by the repositories in the `composer.json` file. Removing all but the primary repository seems to fix the issue.

An example is given below.

Before:

```
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "data-migration-tool": {
        "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool"
    }
}
```

After:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
]
```